# How do I make a stacked bar chart where each bar adds to 100%, but the bars aren't the same height?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I've  never posted here before, but this problem has gotten me so stumped that I felt the need to make a post.

So I have two sets of data:

triplets: this is a list of 32 strings, ex. `["AAA", "ACG", "GAT"...]`

mut_freqs: this is a list of 32 numbers relative to each string in the first list, ex. `[0.12, 0.25, 0.38...]`. This list is sorted from least to greatest, and since the lists are relative to each other, triplets is sorted accordingly. So, we have as an example:

```
triplets = ["AAA", "ACG", "GAT"]
mut_freqs = [0.12, 0.25, 0.38]

# The bar plot for this graph: "Bars that are not the same size"

# for each triplet, we have the probability that the center base will 
# mutate into other bases. For example, for "AAA":
{"AAA": {"ATA": 0.50, "ACA": 0.23, "AGA": 0.27, "AAA": 0}}. # add to 100

# So, now I have:

triplets: ["AAA", "ACG", "GAT"]
A = [0.00, 0.25, 0.00] 
C = [0.23, 0.00, 0.15] 
G = [0.27, 0.25, 0.30]
T = [0.50, 0.50, 0.55]

# The bar plot for this graph: "Bars that are the same size"
```

I want to merge these plots so that the size of the bars is as in the first plot, but they're divided into stacked bars as in the second plot. I have no idea how to do that. Here's my code for the stacked bar graph:

```
A = np.array(A)
T = np.array(T)
C = np.array(C)
G = np.array(G)

plt.bar(triplets, C, color='#ff34dd', edgecolor='white', label = "C")
plt.bar(triplets, G, bottom=C, color='#9c6547', edgecolor='white', label = "G")
plt.bar(triplets, A, bottom=G+C, color='#fce831', edgecolor='white', label = "A")
plt.bar(triplets, T, bottom=A+G+C, color='#50ed25', edgecolor='white', label = "T")

plt.title("Mutation Frequencies of Triplets")
plt.xlabel("Triplet")
plt.ylabel("Mutation Frequency")
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(triplets, rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

The graphs:

Bars that are not the same size

[image]

Bars that are the same size

[image]

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I believe this is a result of the plotted data itself - all the bars in the second plot are the same height when stacked because the stacked probabilities sum to 1.0 for every 'column' in the sample data, i.e. `A[i] + C[i] + G[i] + T[i] = 1.0` for every `i`. This seems to be consistent with the actual data given the line `{"AAA": {"ATA": 0.50, "ACA": 0.23, "AGA": 0.27, "AAA": 0}}. # add to 100`

Comment: Just use `A = np.array(A) * mut_freqs` (similar for C, G and T) which downsizes all bars proportionally to the mutation frequency of each triplet.

Comment: @WilliamMiller, that makes sense! I overlooked that, but it seems so obvious now...

Comment: @JohanC, wow, thanks, I'll definitely try that!